# r extract hour from time data in character format

Tags: r, time, hour

I have a column that stores time data. This is in a character format.

```
c("04:00", "08:55", "15:30", "18:50", "19:15", "12:00")
```

My goal is to extract the hour. I have tried several options , lubridate::hour, chron::hour etc these are not working. I am getting several errors.

The final results should like this below

```
 04, 08, 15, 18, 19, 12
```

Any suggestions ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base R use `substr`:

```
h <- c("04:00", "08:55", "15:30", "18:50", "19:15", "12:00")
substr(h, 1, 2)
#[1] "04" "08" "15" "18" "19" "12"
```

Comment: I am feeling really stupid about this. Thanks Rui this was perfect.

Answer (score 2):

stringr + regex will do the trick

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(string = c("04:00", "08:55", "15:30", "18:50", "19:15", "12:00"),pattern = '^[:digit:]{2}')
[1] "04" "08" "15" "18" "19" "12"
```

Answer (score 0):

just to add a `lubridate` answer:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

t <- c("04:00", "08:55", "15:30", "18:50", "19:15", "12:00")

t %>% 
  hm() %>% 
  hour()
```

You first need to transform your data before using functions in lubridate like `lubridate::hour` or `lubridate::period_to_seconds`. Since your vector is in the format hour:min, then we first use `lubridate::hm`.